# How to disable the backstage Transform tab in Word

Tags: ms-word, vsto, ribbonx

I'm looking to disable the Transform tab in the backstage view of Word 2019. I believe this was introduced in update 1908 (this was when I first noticed it) or thereabouts.

Normally I would set the tab's visibility to false like below but I cannot find the idMso for this anywhere

```
<backstage>
    <tab idMso="TabPublish" visible="false"></tab>
  </backstage>
```

The github page at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers hasn't been updated recently which would normally be my first place to look.

Any idea of where to find the idMso for this tab or a workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Word's Options dialog you can select the `File Tab` and find the `Publish` control:

[image]

The idMso value is `MenuPublish` as shown on the screenshot.

Comment: I don't think you read the question properly.. The **Transform** tab in the **backstage** view is what I'm looking for

Comment: My post gives you an answer where to look for the idMso value. Did you have a chance to look at the `Customize Ribbon` tab of the Word Options dialog?

Comment: The backstage controls are not in the customize ribbon tab